# Given matrix equation $A x = b$, find new matrix $A^*$ after permutation switching $x_i \leftrightarrow b_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrix equation $A x = b$, where $A$ is square, symmetric matrix, how to find new matrix $A^*$ such that:

$A^* x^* = b^*$

and $x^*$, $b^*$ are created by switching vector elements $x_i \leftrightarrow b_i$, using permutation matrix $P_\pi$ on vector $x \choose b$ such that  $ {x^* \choose b^*} = P_\pi {x \choose b}$

[Edit - added example for clarification]

For example :

$x={x_1 \choose x_2}$, $b={b_1 \choose b_2}$, ${x \choose b} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}$, $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\ a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}$

and switching $x_1 \leftrightarrow b_1$ by using permuatation $\pi=\{3,2,1,4\}$:

$P_\pi {x \choose b} =\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}$ we get: $x^*={b_1 \choose x_2}$, $b^*={x_1 \choose b_2}$

Now we want to find matrix $A^*$ such that: $A^* x^* = b^*$. We can do this indirectly rearranging:

$A x = b \iff 
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{1,1} x_1+a_{1,2} x_2 \\
 a_{2,1} x_1+a_{2,2} x_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 b_1 \\
 b_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} \iff
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{1,1} x_1 \\
 a_{2,1} x_1 - b_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 -a_{1,2} x_2 + b_1 \\
  -a_{2,2} x_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
$

and solving for $x_1$, $b_2$ we get:

$A^*=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{a_{1,1}} & -\frac{a_{1,2}}{a_{1,1}} \\ \frac{a_{2,1}}{a_{1,1}} & a_{2,2}-\frac{a_{1,2}a_{2,1}}{a_{1,1}}\end{pmatrix}$

The question is: is there a more direct method to obtain $A^*$?

Comment: Question does not make sense to me. Are you looking for the inverse matrix of $A$?